# Ajax Modal fade in, close and fade out

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, fadein, simplemodal

I made a modal that loads the content from AJAX, it opens up when you click a portfolio item, so that works great :) but i can't get it to fade in, i can't get the modal to close on the cross click and i also need to to fade out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! i have tried everything i can think of i i don't understand why it was not working.

**Clicking to open modal**

```
<a href="works/blk.html" rel="modal:open" class="wolf-media-link" ><img src="img/heno/featured.jpg" alt="Heno"></a>
```

**blk.html content**

```
    <div class="closex"><div class="inner-closex"></div></div>
<div class="modalwindow">
    <section class="portfolio-item blk">
        <div id="description">
            <h1>Blk Sport</h1>
            <h4>Graphic Design</h4>
            <p>BLK is an international sports company I worked for as a graphic designer. Some of my work included print design such as product catalogues and advertisements, EDMs, social media designs, logo designs, user interface design and web design. The web design and product range logo below are purely a conceptual pitch. </p>
        </div>
        <img id="blkwebimage"src="img/blk/web.png">

    </section>
</div>
```

**The JS**

```
    // this needs to fade in
$('.wolf-media-link').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.get(this.href, function(html) {
    $(html).appendTo('body');
  });
});


  $('.closex').on('click', function() { 
//close the modal with a fade out effect
  });
```

And hear is the site i am trying to get it to work on, click a portfolio item :) 
http://arielbeninca.com/ariel.com/

you have no idea how grateful i would be for the help! 
Thankyou so much!!!!!

Comment: you are appending the ajax content received in the `body, why? why not in a div? which is your modal window div which has to hold the ajax data?

Comment: thankyou for your comment 

The modal content comes from a separate html file

you can go to the website and see what i have when you click it 

It opens :) just closing issues...

Comment: use `$('.closex').on('click', function() { $('.modalwindow').fadeOut(); });`

Comment: Still does not work >.< and there is no console error, this is what kept happening to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$("body").on('click','.closex',function(e) {
  $(".modalwindow").fadeOut();
  $(e.target).parent().remove();
})
```

If i am correct this is what you want to happen.
The code needs to be in script with document ready or at the end of the page so the content is loaded correctly before the events fire.

Comment: Glad it helped be sure to mark the answer as the correct one :D

Comment: yeah i was trying to figure out how to do that, then i realised it was the tick!
Thankyou again 

would you have an idea how to make it fade in? 
   $(html).appendTo('body').fadeIn( 600 , 0); < fails

Comment: I would have to check the structure again since its ajax data, im sure that warrants a question of it's own at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

```
In JS

// append fadeIn() method 
$('.wolf-media-link').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.get(this.href, function(html) {
    $(html).appendTo('body').fadeIn();
  });
});

// write below code for fadeOut()
  $('.closex').on('click', function() { 
      $('.modalwindow').fadeOut();
  });   
//if the fadeOut not working you just reload page using 
Window.location.reload(true); into above after fadeOut() method.
```

Comment: Thankyou :)   
  
Unfortunately the close did not work, though Antonio's code closed it :) It also fades out nicely     

Though i still have not been able to get it to fade in :/ even with " $(html).appendTo('body').fadeIn();" it does not work  

This is what i have   

    
       $('.wolf-media-link').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.get(this.href, function(html) {
    $(html).appendTo('body').fadeIn( 600 , 0);
  });
});

      $("body").on('click','.closex',function(e) {
  $(".modalwindow").fadeOut( 600 , 0);
  $(e.target).parent().fadeOut( 600 , 0);
})


Thankyou

Comment: for some reason all my spacing disappeared and i can't fix it, i am new hear

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to know, this code works 100% :)

```
$('.wolf-media-link').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
    $.get(this.href, function(html) {
      $(html).appendTo('body');
      $('.modalwindow').fadeIn(500, function(){
      $(this).addClass('show');
      });
    });
});

$("body").on('click','.closex',function(e) {
  $(".modalwindow").removeClass('show');
  $(e.target).parent().fadeOut(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just add 
`$(idModal).addClass('fade');`
before you call 
`$(idModal).modal('show');`